# How can I pause the program after inserting a variable to avoid inserting another variable in python?

Tags: python, variables

I have written a program in python which takes two variables from the user but I want after it takes one to not take the other one.

I tried with the if loop and the continue funtion after the the first variable so that it continues the program as designed without asking for the second variable

Comment: Please provide code in question. We're reading answers from the magic ball, we need something to base them on.

Comment: If you only want to "take one variable", why do you "take two variables" in the first place?  That's why StackOverflow recommends you *always* create an MRE; so you can demonstrate what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, why it's wrong, etc, with a concrete example which we can test against.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Just read one variable and use a conditional to determine if you want to take a second input.

```
first = input("First variable")
# define second here, so you guarantee that the variable exists 
# in case you don't enter the conditional.
# Otherwise you might have problems later on if you try to access
# a variable that doesn't exist.
# You might want to initialize it to None instead of "".
second = ""  

# change to your actual condition.
if first == "hello":   
    second = input("Second variable")


# the rest of the code goes here.
print(f"First is: {first}")
print(f"Second is: {second}")
```